# How to redirect htaccess to specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, redirect

I have a website that home page is in `site.pt/pt/home` so I need to put in `.htaccess` but I don't know how...

I have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: this is your home site/pt/home to what?

Comment: my home page is site.pt/pt/home @MohammedElhag

Comment: I know it , where you intended to redirect ? you said fro specific url, where is it?

Comment: When I go to site it goes to site.pt and I need that this goes to site.pt/pt/home @MohammedElhag

Comment: there are several solutions so you should try to give more details , do u have want to redirect same pages here there ? or just want to redirect home to home ? does pt directory is exists ? etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this just after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pt/home [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pt/home/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pt/home/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The two conditions are for skipping request that start already with `/pt/home` and the rule redirect all other requests there.